# mysqldump compatible mode postgresql is not working

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I need to convert a mysql database to postgres. Just for testing, I installed a local mysql database and created a simple test database with one table. Now I wan't to make a SQL dump with the option `--compatible=postgresql`:

```
mysqldump test --compatible=postgresql -uroot > ~/Documents/testdump.sql
```

But I always get the following error message:

```
Invalid mode to --compatible: postgresql
```

I'm using OSX and installed mysql using homebrew

the mysql version is: `stable 8.0.12 (bottled)`

I also tried it with the Docker-container and the newest version `8.0.12` but it also gives me the same error message. I need the compatible mode so I can use the dump with an python script to convert it to postgresql.

**Edit**:

I downgraded to `5.7` and it's now working - I'm still wondering why it's not working with the new version.

Answer (score 7):

If you check the documentation for MySQL 8, you will find this:

> --compatible=name
>
> Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or
>   with older MySQL servers. **The only permitted value for this option
>   is ansi**, which has the same meaning as the corresponding option for
>   setting the server SQL mode.

So setting the value of name to postgresql won't work.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible

For `5.7` the following values are possible, which is the reason that a downgrade enabled you to use the desired value:

> --compatible=name
>
> Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or
>   with older MySQL servers. The **value of name can be ansi, mysql323,
>   mysql40, postgresql, oracle, mssql, db2, maxdb, no_key_options,
>   no_table_options, or no_field_options**.